# Rails nested form error, child must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm following the tutorial: http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/

I'm usign Rails 5.0.0.1

But when I register a hotel, it appears that the hotel category must exist.

> 1 error prohibited this hotel from being saved: Categories hotel must
>   exist

My Hotel model:

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
    validates :name, presence: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

My Category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

My hotel controller:

```
def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
    @hotel.categories.build
end

def hotel_params
   params.require(:hotel).permit(:name, categories_attributes: [ :id,:name])
end
```

End my _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :categories do |category| %>  
    <div class="room_category_fields">  
      <div class="field">
        <%= category.label :name %><br>
        <%= category.text_field :name %>
      </div>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`belongs_to` behavior has changed in `rails >= 5.x`. Essentially it is now expected that the `belongs_to` record exists before assigning it to the other side of the association. You need to pass `optional: true` while declaring `belongs_to` in your `Category` model as follows:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel, optional: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I saw that `inverse_of:: categories` also works.

Comment: Thanks Dharam, that's helped. Also, note that `required: false` is deprecated (source: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937). Better use `belongs_to :hotel, optional: true`