# Rails API not receiving cURL POST with nested json correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl

I have a Rails 5 api which should be able to create Visit objects from JSON sent in HTTP POST requests and store that in the database.
The Visit model has an association (has_one) with the VisitComplement model.
The post request that I'm sending with cURL also has fields for this association.

The problem is that the VisitComplement data is not being stored in the database, only the Visit data is being stored.

**Visit model:**

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :visit_complement
  has_one :physical_exam

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :visit_complement

end
```

**VisitsController:**

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @visit = Visit.new(visit_params)

    if @visit.save
      render json: @visit, status: :created, location: @visit
    else
      render json: @visit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
    def visit_params
      params.require(:visit).permit(:fumo, :alcool, visit_complement_attributes: [:sintomas])
    end
end
```

**The cURL POST request:**

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"fumo": "10", "visit_complement_attributes": {"sintomas": "febre"}}'  http://localhost:3000/api/v1/visits
```

When I run the above command I get the following output from the server:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
Started POST "/api/v1/visits" for ::1 at 2016-11-13 16:14:56 -0200
Processing by VisitsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"fumo"=>"10", "visit_complement_attributes"=>{"sintomas"=>"febre"}, "visit"=>{"fumo"=>"10"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "visits" ("fumo", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["fumo", 10], ["created_at", 2016-11-13 18:14:56 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-13 18:14:56 UTC]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 201 Created in 33ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

**Aditional Info**

1. Although it's a rails API, I didn't create it with the --api option.
2. I'm using the rack-cors gem to bypass the CSRF authentication problem
3. I don't have a controller for the VisitComplement model.

Comment: `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.` This is going to be you're problem. You must not have it set up correctly. Please double check that.

Comment: It's not it. This is a security issue that I bypassed with the rack-cors gem.
But just to be sure, I created a new app, using the --api option (in this app I dont have this security issue), but I still have the same problem. It seems that the rails parameter wrapping mechanism, which transforms {"fumo"=>"10", "visit_complement_attributes"=>{"sintomas"=>"febre"} to "visit"=>{"fumo"=>"10"}, is not seeing the association data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. The problem is that my VisitComplement class was like this:

```
class VisitComplement < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :visit
end
```

This belongs_to association expects that the father exists before
creating the child as said here [Rails nested form error, child must exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359168/rails-nested-form-error-child-must-exist)

To solve the problem, either remove the association or add require: false.

Also had to change the visit_params method to:

```
def visit_params
    params.permit(:id, :fumo, :visit_complement_attributes => [:id, :visit_id, :sintomas])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Visit model as shown below.

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :visit_complement
   has_one :physical_exam

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :visit_complement

   attr_accesible :visit_complement_attributes

end
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the following: 
NoMethodError (undefined method `attr_accesible' for #<Class:0x007fc04c13dd28> Did you mean?  attr_accessor):
From what I googled, this is an old method that was deprecated in rails 4 and eliminated in rails 5. I tried the attr_accessor method, but no luck.